# Addition of text element disrupts div layout

Tags: html, css, position

I have 3 divs displayed inline-block that horizontally align:

```
div {
  background:blue;
  height:200px;
  width:30%;
  margin:0px;
  padding:0px;
  border:10px solid red;
  display:inline-block;
  box-sizing:border-box
}
```

[image]

When I add a text element into one of the divs, it's bumped down *(unless the text is `position:absolute;`).
[image]

What is the reason for this?

http://jsbin.com/suweba/2/edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `vertical-align: top` to your `div` using CSS. The default property of `vertical-align` is `baseline` which is why your `div` with the content moves down to the bottom.

Here's a **[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/kenifuhuhi/1/edit?html,css,output)**.

```css
div {
  background: blue;
  height: 200px;
  width: 30%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  border: 10px solid red;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  box-sizing: border-box
}
#b {} text {
  /* position:fixed; */
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="a">
    <text>hello</text>
  </div>
  <div id="b"></div>
  <div id="c"></div>
```

Comment: Could you explain more why that happens? What is the text being vertically aligned with?  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

add `vertical-align: top` when using `display: inline-block`. The natural position of `inline-block` is `baseline`.

[JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/juhugugapo/1/)